# How to add Swing Data Binding to class path?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, data-binding, eclipse-databinding

I'm new to Eclipse and Swing. I wanted to use some Data Binding for my program, and saw here [http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsptopic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.swing.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ffeatures%2Fswing%2Fdata_binding%2Findex.html][1]

> In order to use Swing Data Binding (JSR 295), you must first add the Swing Data Binding jar (e.g., beansbinding-1.2.1.jar) to your classpath

How do I do that? I couldn't google it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is download the jar file itself from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.beansbinding/beansbinding/1.2.1

Then, right-click on your project in the Package Explorer and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path... Select the Libraries tab and then click Add External JARs... Navigate to the location you downloaded the jar file to and select it; now it's in your build path.

Note: If you already had a class open in the WindowBuilder when you did this, you'll have to close it and then reopen it in order to see the Bindings tab.

Hope that helps!